# Sine wave inverter LC filter design

Tags: inverter, low-pass

I have been trying to simulate a full bridge sine wave inverter for 350W using an LC filter. I referred a Texas instruments reference material for the design of LC filter. Switching frequency of 39.5 kHz and 50Hz output frequency. The cut off frequency was chosen as 4kHz. The value of inductance is 5.62 microhenry and capacitor of 281 microfarad. But the output V drops from 230V for greater than 40W and even if I simulate for 350W the issue is the voltage drops to 160V from 230V and the power measured across the load is 180W and not 350W. Can someone suggest me reference materials or help me to design this filter.

Comment: Could you be so kind as to edit your question and add a schematic? After you click on edit, you should get an option to add a schematic. It is the button at the top of the edit box that has some schematic components in it. Another option is to add a screen capture of the circuit you already entered into the simulator you are using.

Comment: In the absence of a schematic it is not possible to make any sense of your question without a raft of assumptions.

Comment: Don't forget that the values for the output LC filter in inverters is not the same as a classical passive LC filter. The inductance is a function of the maximum current and its min/max peak values, and the capacitor needs to withstand the power cycle by cycle, by some amount of ripple. It's similar to the output filter for an SMPS.